# Sending emails using multiple transmitter

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-boot

I'm trying to send emails using spring boot. So I add this starter in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

In my application.yml

```
spring:
 mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    username: xxx@gmail.com
    password: xxxx
    port: 587
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          starttls:
            enable: true
          auth: true
```

this is the method which I use to send emails

```
private EmailStatus sendM(String to, String subject, String text, Boolean isHtml) {
        try {
            MimeMessage mail = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mail, true);

             helper.setFrom("yyy@gmail.com");   // it doesn't work
            helper.setTo(to);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setText(text, isHtml);
            javaMailSender.send(mail);
            LOGGER.info("Send email '{}' to: {}", subject, to);
            return new EmailStatus(to, subject, text).success();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(String.format("Problem with sending email to: {}, error message: {}", to, e.getMessage()));
            return new EmailStatus(to, subject, text).error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

All works fine the problem is that I can't use the method "setFrom" of  email. Wehn I receive emails it's always the email that I set in my application.yml "xxx@gmail.com". Would you have any ideas how I can use multiple spring.mail.username in my application.yml ?

Comment: You can't send email on behalf on some other gmail user.

Comment: Thanks  @RC. But what is the utility of setFrom method ?

Comment: it's used to set the "MAIL FROM" sent to the SMTP server, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example

Comment: Normaly when we use this method "setFrom('xxx@xx.com')" the receive  email must have FROM (xxx@xx.com) But the problem in my case is the FROM email is always which I set in my application.yml